# Azure Site Recovery IP Addressing

Tags: entra-id, azure-networking

I’m setting up Azure Site Recovery and I’ve been told we can migrate machines and retain the IP addresses in Azure, I thought the azure address space needed to be different than on-premise, is it possible to retain all the IPs when migrating workloads to Azure? We will be doing an application at a time over a period of three months. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is possible but quite involved. Take a look at this link for further steps
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/hyper-v-vmm-networking#retain-the-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site Recovery simply by replicating an Azure VM to a different Azure region (Availability Set).Yes,it is possible to retain the IP address without impacting production workloads or end users.

In order to do that the Source (High availability Site) and Target (Disaster Recovery Site) should have IP address with same subnet.

Use Traffic Manager (Priority mode), it moves traffic to the next closest Disaster Recovery Site in Azure region if any one endpoint in unavailable state.If you want to define a preferred failover sequence, use nested Traffic Manager profiles too.

Comment: thanks for that, is this the same for migrating to azure from on premise using asr?

Comment: Yes,you can do the same steps as you would for full disaster recovery.
Configure replication with extra priority,most of the time you will face issue during replication. 
Keep in mind that replication from Azure to on-premises can happen just over the site to site VPN or over the private peering of your ExpressRoute arrange. 
Guarantee that separate master target server with enough data transfer capacity is accessible over that system channel and each virtual machine template has its own UUID for the disks.

Comment: Note : Fail-back from Azure to an on-premises physical server isn't as of now. You can just fail-back to a VMware virtual machine.

Comment: @Aiden Your suggesting of traffic manager may not apply. If OP is only using these servers internally he will likely need to consider a stretched VLAN, ip routing change or DNS update to complete failover.